# Double subnets for a site (AD)

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I am trying to create Subnets in existing Sites loaded in from a .txt file. My code looks like this:

```
<#Add subnets to matching sites#>
        $i=0
        foreach($_ in $subnetList){
            $currentSites = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest().Sites
            if($currentSites.Subnets -match $_){
                continue
            }else{                            
                New-ADReplicationSubnet -Name $_ -Site $siteList[$i]
                $i++
            }
        }
```

The `$subnetList` and the `$siteList` have the following content:

```
$subnetList = 
    10.0.0.0/21
    10.0.5.0/21
    10.0.9.0/24
    10.0.11.0/24
    10.0.14.0/24
    10.0.19.0/24

<#SITENAME1 has 2 occurences.#>
$siteList = 
    SITENAME1
    SITENAME1
    SITENAME2
    SITENAME3
    SITENAME4
    SITENAME5
```

The problem I run into is that when SITENAME1 has the first subnet added it returns an error on the second attempt:

```
New-ADReplicationSubnet : An attempt was made to add an object to the directory 
with a name that is already in use
```

Is there any way to still add an extra subnet to this Site? Technet talks about the `-Instance` switch. I am not sure on how to implement that I'm afraid.

EDIT: I also asked this exact same question on StackOverflow to no avail. Seeing as this is perhaps more of an Active Directory oriented community I wanted to try my luck here. If this is against the rules I will delete my question.

Comment: `Is there any way to still add an extra subnet to this Site?` - **Why.** This would be a broken configuration.

Comment: Well to be deadly honest with you, this is for an assignment, so I am just trying to do as it states. 

Would you mind explaining why that would break the configuration? Perhaps with a grounded explanation I can justify me modifying the assignment.

Comment: Because 10.0.0.0/21 includes all addresses in the range between 10.0.0.0 and 10.0.7.255. The definition of 10.0.5.0/21 is overlapping the first one (in fact, it is an identity). You *can* add another subnet, it is just that you cannot add a subnet overlapping one already defined for any other site.

Comment: @syneticon-dj Overlapping subnets are most certainly supported. They take precedence by granularity meaning that the smallest matching subnet's site applies. These two are not overlapping though, they're just the same subnet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, having 2 separate lists with corresponding key->value pairs is not that bright, but let's work with it.

The current conditional logic of your script will never detect existing subnets. `$currentSites` will always be a collection of sites, not a single site object. The collection has no `Subnets` parameter and the statement will always return false, since one is always `$null` and one is always a string.

Retrieving the entire site list on each iteration is both time consuming and unnecessary, let's try and work with the data we already have instead

Since index `n` in the `$siteList` array always corresponds to index `n` in the `$subnetList` array, let's use a regular for loop with a common counter `$n`:

```
for ($n = 0; $n -lt $subnetList.Count; $n++)
{
    // Let's see if the subnet exists, and what site it's assigned to
    $existingSubnet = Get-ADReplicationSubnet $subnetList[$n] -Properties Site -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    if(-not($existingSubnet))
    {
        // None exist already, go ahead
        New-ADReplicationSubnet $subnetList[$n] -Site $siteList[$n]
    }
    else
    {
        if(($existingSubnet.Site).ToString() -ne $siteList[$n])
        {
            // It exists but not in the right site
            Set-ADReplicationSubnet $subnetList[$n] -Site $siteList[$n]
        }
    }
}
```

Do yourself a favor though, consolidate the two files into a single CSV file. Then you can use `foreach` all you want :-)

Semicolon separated CSV example (SitesNSubnets.csv):

```
Subnet;SiteName
10.0.0.0/21;SITENAME1
10.0.5.0/21;SITENAME1
10.0.9.0/24;SITENAME2
10.0.11.0/24;SITENAME3
10.0.14.0/24;SITENAME4
10.0.19.0/24;SITENAME5
```

And then use [`Import-CSV`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176874.aspx) to import it:

```
$data = Import-CSV -Path .\SitesNSubnets.csv -Delimiter ";"

foreach ($entry in $data)
{
    Write-Host "This is the subnet: " + $entry.Subnet + " and this is the corresponding site: " $entry.SiteName
}
```

Comment: This worked perfect for me. However, what do you mean, merging the two variables into one .csv file? How would I go abouts calling for example the subnet on the second line of the .csv? Seeing as $a = gc "FILEPATH";$a[2] would return a complete line?

Comment: Treat it as a CSV ;-) updated example

Answer (score 2):

A subnet object, when linked to a site object, tells both Active Directory and the member server what site the domain member server belongs to.

You cannot add duplicate subnet objects to Active Directory.

You cannot link a subnet object to multiple sites.

You **can** make use of subnet objects that contain overlapping address space.

Unless your servers are using some form of IT quantum physics I don't know about, it makes no sense for a server to belong to both the 'Miami' site and the 'Dallas' site simultaneously, does it?

What you can do is define smaller, more specific subnets within a larger subnet, to different sites.  For instance, you could assign the 10.0.0.0/8 subnet to Dallas, and then you could assign the 10.2.0.0/16 to Miami.  Active Directory will give precedence to the more specific subnet. You could even add a /32 subnet object to Active Directory if you wanted to force one specific host to authenticate to a particular site.

```
<#SITENAME1 has 2 occurences.#>
$siteList = 
    SITENAME1
    SITENAME1
```

**WHY?!?!** What sense does that make? As Zoredache said, this is broken. You can't have two sites with the same name.

Here is me trying to add a site named Arlington when I already have a site named Arlington:

[image]

Here I am defining several subnet objects, all linked to the same site, of which both the 10.1.2.64/26 subnet and the 10.0.0.0/24 network fit inside the 10.0.0.0/8 'supernet:'

[image]

Comment: Right, just to clarify, when I have a Server in the 10.0.0.0/21 subnet and a different server in the 10.0.5.0/21 subnet those seperate subnets will never be in the same location (for example) Dallas? Because to me that could be two seperate LAN infrastructures on one geographical location? The way I see it, I am not trying to assign duplicate subnets, I am just trying to add another, non-related subnet to an existing site object.

Comment: A subnet object in AD DS groups neighboring computers in much the same way that postal codes group neighboring postal addresses. By associating a site with one or more subnets, you assign a set of IP addresses to the site. <- This comes straight from technet.

Comment: Oh. Well then OP, you get a two-fer. Your Powershell is wonky *and* you learned about AD Sites & Subnets. Thanks @MathiasR.Jessen.